# How to get GCP cloud-function CPU time stats

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a higher than expected cost for my cloud functions this month.  Is there a view or API call that shows me exactly how much CPU time is being used by each function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [all available metrics](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/metrics) that you can pull for Cloud Functions, and here you can see all the [monitoring metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-cloudfunctions) that you can use in Stackdriver, as you can see execution_count(how many executions) and execution_times(how long do they last) are the closest to something that would be useful for you.

There is no option to see CPU usage as far as I know,due to how, I assume, Cloud Functions are executed and the main philosophy behind them being stateless. So if your execution time and your invocations have increased, that increase in the billing amount is observable.

In order to better understand the higher than expected cost having a look at how [compute billing is calculated](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#compute_time) might help you out.

**EDIT:**
If you want to have more control of your expenses on Cloud Functions you can attempt to set [rate limits/instance limits](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas) and [max limits](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances).

Hope this helps.

**EDIT2:**

In order to be able to see your execution_count for your functions in StackDriver, follow the next steps.

1. Go to your GCP Project.
2. In the navigation menu (where all the products are) go to "Monitoring" product.
3. Once in Stackdriver hover your mouse over "Resources" then click on "Metrics Explorer".
4. Where "Find resource type and metric" type "function".
5. Choose "Executions" in order to see the executions.

If you click on "+Add a filter" you can specify the function name that you want to filter.

Comment: Thank you so much.  It's weird that I'm being billed in CPU hours, but I can see where those CPU hours are coming from.

Comment: I can't figure out how to see the execution_count for my functions in stackdriver.

Comment: Have a look at my edit, hope that helps.

If that solves your issues please consider accepting/upvoting my answer in order to help other members of the community.